# Unsaved tabs all get the same name if page is refreshed

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create some tabs but don't click save:

   [image]
2. Save one of the tabs, for example `t2` in this case:

   [image]
3. Refresh the page (F5):

   [image]

   All my tabs are now named `t2` which was the one I initially saved.

I guess what I expected was either one of the following:

- lose all the new unsaved tabs leaving me with just `t2`
- the unsaved tab names might be cached somewhere (browser or serverside), it does after all remember the number of tabs I created.

This was tested on Chrome 46.0.2490.80m running on Windows 10 Pro x64.

Comment: Footnote: Step three might not be necessary, but I was pushed for time and couldn't test without that step.

Comment: I just repo'd without step three on the same version of Chrome on Windows 7.

Comment: @Kendra - thanks, just edited question to reflect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in build `#3919` (meta.stackoverflow.com) and build `#3024` (stackoverflow.com).